# Unwanted {} appearing in app, which copies text from the Java script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a total beginner to programming, and am currently following the One Month Rails tutorials to try and learn the basics of Ruby Rails.

I seem to have made a mistake somewhere in my code, as a {} is appearing just below the header of all the pages in my app. When you log in, and Java says "Signed in successfully", the text is copied into the {} like so {:notice=>"Signed in successfully."}.

You can see this at

http://cryptic-sands-6348.herokuapp.com/

https://github.com/jackwatson/omrails/tree/master/app/views/layouts

I have checked through my code in the app>views>layouts and pages folders but can not seem to find where the mistake is made.

If anyone knows an answer to this I would be very grateful for the help :) and sorry for the n00b question

Comment: You will need to share the code of your `layout/application.html.erb` or haml file for people here to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/jackwatson/omrails/tree/master/app/views/layouts hope this helps

Comment: It's not really very nice to say "go look at my code and fix it". It's better to include some of it, preferably a minimally-failing example, like in this case, the issue is reproducible on a page with an empty view (i.e., just the layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is on line #13 of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Change

```
<%= flash.each do |name, msg| %>
```

to

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
```

`<%= ... %>` outputs the result of Ruby code as a string, `<% ... %>` just executes the code.

You just want to execute the Ruby code, not display the output of `each`, which will be an empty hash if there are no errors.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help, and the explanation of why it was doing that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">{}<div class="hero-unit">
```

found that in your code. if you dont want the "{}", just remove it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I can see the "{}" in the code when I use "inspect elements", but can't find it in the text files. They're here if this helps https://github.com/jackwatson/omrails/tree/master/app/views/layouts

Comment: oh i understand what you mean now, but sorry i cant i help you.
edit your first question and add the link to it : github.com/jackwatson/omrails/tree/master/app/views/layouts 
so you have a better chance to get the right answer :)